# Eclipse virtual application deploy Vs ear deploy

Tags: eclipse, web-applications, weblogic, virtual, web-deployment

I have a Java EE web application written in Eclipse and deployed on WebLogic.

When I deploy it from Eclipse (as a virtual application) it works fine. When I try to create an EAR file and deploy it from the WebLogic console I get a `ClassNotFoundException`.

What could be the reason?

How can I create an EAR file that will match the structure of the virtual application so it will work?

Answer (score 0):

Usually this means a dependent library is not being deployed. This tends to be where Eclipse has a dependency which it fulfills as part of the internal build. When building it yourself, work out which libraries you need, and which are part of your application, and which are part of WebLogic. For your own libraries (ie those in the lib folders, or those that SHOULD be in the lib folder) make sure they are on the classpath. For external libraries, ie those WebLogic fulfills, make sure you have the appropriate schema descriptors setup to tell weblogic which libraries it needs to deploy with your application (typically things like JSF).

If you want proper control over the build, take a look at things like Ant. You basically tell it via xml what is needed, put it together, and it generates the Ear/Jar file for you (the Ear file containing all the dependencies as well, and/or with your descriptors for weblogic built in libraries).

If you are planning many builds, I find Ant useful once setup (you can tie it in with other programs too, so it can push a build to your Source Control Server as a tag, build documentation, etc). Ant can be a pain though- you need build descriptors for each library you need to build, as well as the Ear file.